# If I begin a mass file deletion on a network share folder, what is the load on my local PC and what is the load on the network share PC/device?

Tags: windows, network-shares, file-management

All questions are based on Windows 7 64-bit PCs and/or a Synology NAS.

I'm going through an aging file server and cleaning up thousands of old documents including e-mails and attachments and tons of random junk.  After I archive a folder full of stuff I'm removing it from this server.  Sometimes the stuff has been duplicated on a NAS device so I need to delete it there as well.

My question is, *when I tell a remote computer or device to delete (using Windows Explorer <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>) say, ~14,000 files totaling 5GB, what is the load on my local PC and what is the load on the share in terms of CPU and memory?*

I've noticed that on the local computer the memory usage does not seem to be impacted.  The CPU usage is between 2% and 8%, doesn't seem significant.

The Synology NAS has only 1GB of memory, and the file deletion is much slower.  It is a 2-bay with 2TB drives in RAID 1, I'm pretty sure it has an ARM chip.

Another question, *does my local machine just send a command to the share and then give me a progress bar to watch?*  If so, I guess the progress bar and monitoring would be the only thing consuming resources... right?

P.S. I know there are faster ways to delete.  I'm not in a hurry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right. Your computer sende the commands to the share, and the NAS has all the work deleting the files.

The NAS will send a message to your PC after each file is deleted. Your PC will calculate the progress Bar.

In addition your computer queries the file system of the NAS from time to time to see how many files are still there.